# I'm installing octave for Yosemite. I'm having trouble in a specific step in the process. Any ideas?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

I'm following the procedure given on this site: http://adampash.com/how-to-install-octave/

I've been stuck in this step for quite a while:

> Last, you need to edit your .octaverc file to get gnuplot to play
>   nicely with Octave. So, in your home directory, create a new .octaverc
>   file and paste the following:

```
# # ~/.octaverc
setenv ("GNUTERM", "X11")

# #below is optional; changes the prompt to two chevron
# and gets rid of the long Octave x.x.x >> prompt
PS1('❯❯ ')
```

I want to know what to specifically type in terminal. How do I create the .octaverc file? Where do I paste the following instructions?

Comment: *How do I create the .octaverc file?* Use a text editor. [Mac text/code editor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20533/1115360)

Answer (score 1):

Use any editor to create the file .octaverc in your home directory,
In the editor just paste the text

```
setenv ("GNUTERM", "X11")
```

**below is optional; changes the prompt to two chevron
and gets rid of the long Octave x.x.x >> prompt**

```
PS1('❯❯ ')
```

You will  find yourself in your home directory by typing

```
$ cd ~
```

The path can be shown by

```
$pwd
```

That is where you must place the file .octaverc.

Good luck!
Martijn